# Deploying a smart contract for the second time (version2) and read/writing from etherscan.io

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, etherscan, nft, truffle-deployment

I successfully deployed my smart contract that enables me to mint NFTs. Now I know that everything on the blockchain is permanent, so if I wanted to make changes to that contract, I have to deploy a "v2" of the same contract with changes. Now the problem is that the second time I deploy, I don't have access to the `Contract` tab options like `Read Contract` and `Write Contract` unlike the first time I deployed:

[image]

Instead, this is what I see:

[image]

I'm confused... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless the contract is verified you won't have access to those sections.

Comment: How did my first deployment of the contract got it verified in the first place?

Comment: If you deploy a contract that has exactly the same bytecode that another contract that was already verified on etherscan will show it as verified. That is quite easy to do if you used the source code from a tutorial, public github repo, etc.

Comment: @Ismael Ah! Makes sense why It was already verified when I deployed it. It is from a online course's github repo. In that case, how to you verify a smart contract on etherscan??

Comment: In the image you sent youtself, see that there is a link "verify and publish". It will ask you to copy and paste the contract you wrote.